# Active Directory. Anyone else have the Everyone Group across OU structure with deny deletechild uninherited?

Tags: powershell

I have a domain that has the following and cannot explain why its setup at all. Does anyone else have this and know why its setup?

Entire Tree's of OUs are found to have an ACL for the everyone group that is:

1. not inherited
2. applies only to the OU
3. explicitly denies a variation of deleteChild, DeleteTree and Delete.

Does anyone else see something like this in their domain?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJTRq.png):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJTRq.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ndpx.png

Comment: Is there also no documentation about it? Maybe a previous Admin implemented it for a reason

Answer (score 0):

That ACE entry is added when the box is checked for "protect this object from accidental deletion". It is added to new OUs by default.